# OpenAPI Generator: Initialize List properties as null and not as empty Lists

Tags: java, list, openapi, openapi-generator

**Problem:**
When I generate a class with the openAPI code generator properties with a List type are initialized right away as an empty ArrayList.
I want to remove this initialization, so that this property can be null.
How can I do this in the openAPI specification?

**Use-Case:**
For my merge-patch operation, I need to distinguish between giving an empty list as parameter or not specifying the parameter at all.
I would expect that I get an empty list when the parameter is given but contains an empty List and null if the parameter is not given.

Answer (score 1):

The option `containerDefaultToNull` let you choose if `null` or empty (List, Map), see the [doc](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md#config-options).

But it seems the generated code/parser won't distinguish a `null` or empty input. I'm not sure about it, you should analyse the generated code for that.